# how to retrieve other-peers-id using PeerServer

Tags: node.js, peerjs

I want to make a video chat application using peerJs and PeerServer. I am passing an ID which is randomly generated when creating a peer constructor. This is what I have on the client side

```
        var generatedID = $('#my_id').text();

        var peer = new Peer( generatedID , { host: 'localhost', port: 7880, path: '/' });
```

and then I create a connection, from their documentation in GitHub, we pass the other peer's id to initialize the connection.

```
        var conn = peer.connect('another-peers-id');
        conn.on('open', function(){
              // the the logic here
        });
```

Now, I am wondering how to obtain the other peer's id.

Answer (score 0):

I looked API i didn't see anything about it. So you can count yourself. So you can define an array for current peers.

```
var currentConnectionSize = 0;
var peers = [];

conn.on('connection', function(id){
    peers.push(id);
    currentConnectionSize++;
    console.log(currentConnectionSize);
});

conn.on('disconnected', function(id){
    peers.slice(peers.indexOf(id),1);
    currentConnectionSize--;
    console.log(currentConnectionSize);
});
```

Maybe you need define it for "error" and "close" events.

Comment: may be my question was not clear, the logic I want to implement is, get the other-peers-id in order to make a connection between the two peers and allow them to communicate and send messages